# Floating point calculations in a processor with no FPU

Tags: c, operating-system, cpu-architecture, fpu

Is it possible to perform floating point operations in an embedded processor that does not have a Floating Point Unit?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you just have to do it in software.  Your [compiler may provide support](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html), or you may need to roll your own.  There are [freely-available implementations](http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/SoftFloat.html), too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, e.g. early Linux kernels did emulate i387 floating point instructions in the kernel. It was rather slow, but allowed you to use the same binary on computers with and without a floating point unit.